# Question on linear independence of particular vectors of $\mathbb{R}^8$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Given any four points $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4\in \mathbb{C}$, all different from zero, consider the following seven vectors of $\mathbb{C}^4$:
$$v_1:=(0,z_2-0,0,0)$$
$$v_2:=(0,0,z_3-0,0)$$
$$v_3:=(z_1-z_2,z_2-z_1,0,0)$$
$$v_4:=(0,z_2-z_4,0,z_4-z_2)$$
$$v_5:=(0,0,z_3-z_4,z_4-z_3)$$
$$v_6:=(z_1-z_3,0,z_3-z_1,0)$$
$$v_7:=(z_1-z_4,0,0,z_4-z_1)$$
Under what conditions on $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are these seven vectors $v_1,\dots,v_7$ linearly independent as vectors of $\mathbb{R}^8$?

Of course I know how to consider the vectors $v_i$ as vectors of $\mathbb{R}^8$. The difficult part (which is the aim of the question) is to deduce all sufficient conditions for their linear independence.

Edit: User MvG posted an answer which involves the use of a computer algebra system, but I am actually interested in a method which could be solved by hand (without a computer).

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing $z_k=a_k+ib_k$ with $a_k,b_k\in\mathbb R$ for your complex numbers.

The $7$ vectors are independent over the reals iff *none* of the following conditions is satisfied:

1. $a_2b_3 = a_3b_2$
2. $a_1b_2 + a_2b_4 + a_4b_1 = a_1b_4 + a_4b_2 + a_2b_1$
3. $a_1b_3 + a_3b_4 + a_4b_1 = a_1b_4 + a_4b_3 + a_3b_1$

You can also reformulate these conditions in terms of determinants:

$$
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a_2&a_3&0\\b_2&b_3&0\\1&1&1\end{array}\right|=0
\qquad
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a_1&a_2&a_4\\b_1&b_2&b_4\\1&1&1\end{array}\right|=0
\qquad
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}a_1&a_3&a_4\\b_1&b_3&b_4\\1&1&1\end{array}\right|=0
$$

You could also take the product of these, as the product will be zero if any of its factors is zero.

Interpreting these determinants geometrically (interpreting $z_k$ as points in the [complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane)), the first is zero if $z_2,z_3,0$ are collinear (i.e. $z_2$ is a real multiple of $z_3$ or vice versa), the second for $z_1,z_2,z_4$ collinear and the third for $z_1,z_3,z_4$ collinear.

I got these conditions out of the following [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) computation, which I'll explain below:

```
sage: R.<a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3,a4,b4> = QQ[]  # declare polynomial ring
sage: M = matrix([
....: [    0,     0,    a2,    b2,     0,     0,     0,     0],
....: [    0,     0,     0,     0,    a3,    b3,     0,     0],
....: [a1-a2, b1-b2, a2-a1, b2-b1,     0,     0,     0,     0],
....: [    0,     0, a2-a4, b2-b4,     0,     0, a4-a2, b4-b2],
....: [    0,     0,     0,     0, a3-a4, b3-b4, a4-a3, b4-b3],
....: [a1-a3, b1-b3,     0,     0, a3-a1, b3-b1,     0,     0],
....: [a1-a4, b1-b4,     0,     0,     0,     0, a4-a1, b4-b1]])
sage: ideal(M.minors(7)).minimal_associated_primes()
[Ideal (-b1*a3 + a1*b3 + b1*a4 - b3*a4 - a1*b4 + a3*b4) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4 over Rational Field,
 Ideal (-b1*a2 + a1*b2 + b1*a4 - b2*a4 - a1*b4 + a2*b4) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4 over Rational Field,
 Ideal (-b2*a3 + a2*b3) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4 over Rational Field]
```

The vectors are linearily dependent if all the $7\times7$ [minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) are zero. There are $8$ such minors. Now you could simply write down all the polynomial equations you get from the minors and declare that to be your condition. But probably you are looking for some simpler solution, in terms of the amount of formulas you have to write.

The solutions of this system of polynomial equations form an [algebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_set) which can be described using an [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) generated by these minors. That ideal contains the set of all polynomials in $R:=\mathbb Q[a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3,a_4,b_4]$ which are zero for every solution.

The ideal is not [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal), so the algebraic set is not an irreducible algebraic variety, but the union of several such varieties. To describe these irreducible varieties, one can do a [primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition) of the ideal and then take the [associated primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime) for each component.

The [documentation for `associated_primes`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.html#sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_ideal.MPolynomialIdeal_singular_repr.associated_primes) writes:

> Return a list of the associated primes of primary ideals of which the
>   intersection is $I$ = `self`.
>
> An ideal $Q$ is called primary if it is a proper ideal of the ring $R$ and if whenever $ab \in Q$ and $a \not\in Q$ then $b^n \in Q$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$.
>
> If $Q$ is a primary ideal of the ring $R$, then the radical ideal $P$ of $Q$, i.e. $P = \{a \in R, a^n \in Q\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$, is called the *associated prime* of $Q$.
>
> If $I$ is a proper ideal of the ring $R$ then there exists a decomposition in primary ideals $Q_i$ such that
>
> - their intersection is $I$
> - none of the $Q_i$ contains the intersection of the rest, and
> - the associated prime ideals of $Q_i$ are pairwise different.
>
> This method returns the associated primes of the $Q_i$.

The intersection of ideals corresponds to the union of algebraic sets. (This aspect has taken me a while to wrap my head around.) And going from the primary component $Q_i$ to the associated prime of that simplifies things. For example, if you have an ideal which contains $z_1^3$ as a generator, then the only way to satisfy the condition $z_1^3=0$ is by $z_1=0$. Thus dropping the power means you get the same zero set with simpler generators.

The function [`minimal_associated_primes`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.html#sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_ideal.MPolynomialIdeal_singular_repr.minimal_associated_primes) has insufficient documentation. Reading [the code](https://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/tree/src/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.py?h=8.1#n1565) suggests looking at the [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) function `MinAssGTZ` for details, but [the documentation for that](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-3/sing_1321.htm) isn't too great either. Anyway, I would assume that the minimal associated primes are all associated primes (as described above) which are not supersets of associated primes of other components. I'm using this function as computing all associated primes takes longer than I care to wait.

Comment: Where complex vs real numbers enter the picture in your solution? The OP wants these 7 complex vectors to be independent in a $8$ dimensional real space. So, it becomes a $7\times 8$ real matrix, why the $4\times 4$ complex minors are checked?

Comment: @Berci: This is fully complex-valued. I see no gain in writing this using real values, but you could of course rewrite each of my complex-valued equations to two real-valued ones, one for the real part and one for the imaginary part, to have equations in 8 real variables.

Comment: @MvG thank you for your answer. Unluckily I am interested in sufficient conditions for independence, I am trying to figure out if replacing the vectors with linear combinations one can obtain such conditions

Comment: @user389604: I did some more research on the subjects involved, and now I feel more confident that my answer is indeed the right one for both necessary and sufficient conditions. I'll update my post soon.

Comment: Wait a sec, I think I have the whole thing transposed in my mind: I'm essentially talking about full rank of the matrix, but that rank would be 4 not 7. Will undelete once I've re-evaluated the question if there is still any point in this answer.

Comment: @Berci: I didn't think this through; your comment was spot-on and I should have been doing this over the reals from the beginning. Full rank over the reals and over the complex numbers are different things. And rank $7$ over the complex numbers doesn't make any sense here. Sorry it took me so long to recognize the value of your comment.

Comment: @MvG thank you, so if I understand correctly you search the decomposition in prime ideals of the ideal generated by all 7 minors of the matrix. I am actually searching for a method which does not involve any computer algebra system, so is there a way to do it by hand without sage?

Comment: @user389604: Since the conditions turn out to be one equation each, not a conjunction of multiple equations, it is possible to find these conditions as factors of the minors. So if you manage to factorize the minors manually, you will find the conditions from that, and *might* be able to conclude that there are no further components. But right now I don't have a good idea how to get certainty on the latter part.

Comment: @MvG thank you very much for your effort. I am actually looking for a method which can be performed without the use of a computer algebra system. I will start a bounty for an answer which solves it by hand and if no better answer will be posted I will award it to yours

Answer (score 2):

Because $\mathbb{R}^8_\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}^4_\mathbb{R}$ are isomoprhic this is equivalent to finding conditions so that $V = \{v_1, ...,v_7\}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear independent.

Let $x = (x_1, ..., x_7) \in \mathbb{R}^7$. We want to obtain conditions on $V$ such that
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^7 x_n v_n = 0 \implies \forall n \in 1...7, x_n = 0 $$

Since a zero vector would immediately ruin the linear independence of $V$ assume for a while that $z_1 \neq z_2$, $z_2 \neq z_4$, $z_3 \neq z_4$, $z_1 \neq z_3$ and $z_1 \neq z_4$. Later some of these will be replaced by stronger conditions.

Writing the equation $\sum\limits_{n=1}^7 x_n v_n = 0$ in matrix form we get

$$ \underbrace{ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 0 & z_1-z_2 & 0 & 0 & z_1-z_3 & z_1-z_4 \\
 z_2 & 0 & z_2-z_1 & z_2-z_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & z_3 & 0 & 0 & z_3-z_4 & z_3-z_1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & z_4-z_2 & z_4-z_3 & 0 & z_4-z_1 \\
\end{array}
\right] }_{\displaystyle A} x = 0 $$

Row reducing $A$
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc} \displaystyle
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{z_4-z_3}{z_2} & \dfrac{z_1-z_3}{z_2} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{z_3-z_4}{z_3} & \dfrac{z_3-z_1}{z_3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_2} & \dfrac{z_1-z_4}{z_1-z_2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{z_3-z_4}{z_2-z_4} & 0 & \dfrac{z_4-z_1}{z_4-z_2} \\
\end{array}
\right] x = 0$$

Multiplying $Ax$ and equating elements yields
$$ x_2 = -x_1 \frac{z_2}{z_3} \tag{1} $$
$$ x_3 = x_1 \frac{z_2}{z_1-z_2} - x_7 \frac{z_1-z_4}{z_1-z_2} - x_5 \frac{z_3-z_4}{z_1-z_2} \tag{2} $$
$$ x_4 = - x_5 \frac{z_3-z_4}{z_2-z_4} - x_7 \frac{z_4-z_1}{z_4-z_2} \tag{3} $$
$$ x_6 = -x_1 \frac{z_2}{z_1-z_3} -x_5 \frac{z_4-z_3}{z_1-z_3} \tag{4} $$

Note that because $\dim\ker A \ge 3$ there will be at least $3$ free variables and this means that there are other ways of manipulating these equations. Nonetheless, every way will result in equivalent conclusions.

Starting by the simpler equation: $(1)$ we make $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ by requiring that $\operatorname{Im}{(\dfrac{z_2}{z_3})} \neq 0$.

Now setting $x_1 = 0$ in $(4)$, the same reasoning leads to requiring $\operatorname{Im}{(\dfrac{z_4-z_3}{z_1-z_3})} \neq 0$. Hence $x_5 = x_6 = 0$.

Similarly for $(3)$, we require $\operatorname{Im}{(\dfrac{z_4-z_1}{z_4-z_2})} \neq 0$. Then $x_4 = x_7 = 0$.

Thus $(2)$ yields $x_3 = 0$.

Therefore we conclude that the following six conditions are sufficient for $V$ to be $\mathbb{R}$-L.I.:

1. $z_1 \neq z_2$
2. $z_1 \neq z_3$
3. $z_2 \neq z_4$
4. $\operatorname{Im}{(\dfrac{z_2}{z_3})} \neq 0$
5. $\operatorname{Im}{(\dfrac{z_4-z_3}{z_1-z_3})} \neq 0$
6. $\operatorname{Im}{(\dfrac{z_4-z_1}{z_4-z_2})} \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but an attempt which would hopefully be helpful.  We can consider $\mathbb{C}^n$ to be $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ by identifying $\begin{bmatrix}x_1+iy_1\\\vdots\\x_n+iy_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\ x_n\\y_1\\\vdots\\ y_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.  The given problem looks like an instance of the following setting.

Let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha_j=\beta_j+i\gamma_j$.  Let $\beta=\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\vdots\\\beta_n\end{bmatrix},\,\gamma=\begin{bmatrix}\gamma_1\\\vdots\\\gamma_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then by our identification, we have $\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\vdots\\\alpha_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}$.

Now we have vectors $v_l,\,l=1,\ldots,s$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, where with respect to the standard basis, each coordinate of $v_l$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of $\alpha_i$'s.  So we have matrices $T_l\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $v_l=\begin{bmatrix}T_l&0\\0&T_l\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix},\quad l=1,\ldots,s$.

For the given example, we have $\beta=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix},\,\gamma=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\\y_4\end{bmatrix}$.  Further,

$$T_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad T_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad T_3=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\-1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad T_4=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$T_5=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&-1&1\end{bmatrix},\quad  T_6=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\1&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&0\\-1&0&1&0\end{bmatrix},\quad T_7=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\-1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

It can be checked that $\{T_1,\ldots,T_7\}$ is linearly independent in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.  Define $\phi:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as $\phi(T)=\begin{bmatrix}T&0\\0&T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}$.  Then $\phi(T_i)=v_i,\,i=1,\ldots,7$.  Let $W=\text{span}\{T_1,\ldots,T_7\}$.  Then $\{v_1,\ldots,v_7\}$ are linearly independent if and only if $\phi|_W$ is injective.

Comment: thank you, but proving $\phi|_W$ is injective seems as difficult as proving $v_i$ are linearly indepedent

Comment: Yes, realized that just now.  Doesn't really make the job easier.  Sorry couldn't help.